# GetX Throwing TypeError when try to build with Obx

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I have controller call `MenuController`

```
class MenuController extends GetxController {
  var currentCategory = Rx<int>(0);
  @override
  void onReady() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2000));
  }

  void setMenuByIndex(int index) {
    currentCategory.value = index;
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to check selected index from simple Widget like this

```
Obx(() => Text(controller.currentCategory.value.toString()))
```

Getting controller like here

```
final controller = Get.find<MenuController>();
```

Im getting the error

```
type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'Rx<int>' of 'function result'
```

Comment: I think there is no problem in your code. I've tested your code and works. `Obx(() => Text(controller.currentCategory.value.toString()))`  was changed if I set new value using `setMenuByIndex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this...

```
 class MenuController extends GetxController {
  Rx<int> currentCategory = Rx<int>(0);
  @override
  void onReady() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2000));
  }

  void setMenuByIndex(int index) {
    currentCategory.value = index;
  }
}
```